# Buffer resource as shader resource view

Tags: c++, directx11

I am trying to build a shader that change the output color according to something that happen in my c++ code

In my code I create a buffer with four element(each element containe four float - RGBA)

then I create four shader resource view associate with that buffer.
the first shader resource view contain the first element in the array the second shader resource view contain the second element in the array and so on.

in my code there is no exceptions and I can see in the diagnostic that my correct shader resource view with the correct resource associate to the pixel shader but in my pixel shader I get nothing.

Here is my pixel shader:

```
cbuffer cbChangesEveryFrame : register( b0 )
{
matrix worldMatrix;
};
cbuffer cbNeverChanges : register( b1 )
{
    matrix viewMatrix;
};
cbuffer cbChangeOnResize : register( b2 )
{
    matrix projMatrix;
};
float4 outPutColor : register(s0);
struct VS_Input
{
    float4 pos  : POSITION;
};
struct PS_Input
{
    float4 pos  : SV_POSITION;
};
PS_Input VS_Main( VS_Input vertex )
{
    PS_Input vsOut = ( PS_Input )0;
    vsOut.pos = mul( vertex.pos, worldMatrix );
    vsOut.pos = mul( vsOut.pos, viewMatrix );
    vsOut.pos = mul( vsOut.pos, projMatrix );

    return vsOut;
}
float4 PS_Main( PS_Input frag ) : SV_TARGET
{
    return outPutColor;
    //return float4(0,0,1,1);
}
```

The shader resource view should associate to outPutColor but when I debug the shader I get four float of zero.
Why I getting zero instead my buffer?

Comment: Why not use that ouputColor vector as a shader constant? Resource views are for textures. Update it like the rest of your constant buffers.

Comment: I want to check if my shader resource view work

Comment: Can you give me example of shader resource view?

Comment: Textures can be bound to a shader by their shaderresourceviews for example. You'd need to declare a **Texture2D ouputColorTex : register(t0);** in your shader for instance.

Comment: So why I can not do this with buffers?

Comment: Create a buffer with D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER instead of D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE in your case. Textures are also buffers hovewer, but they are declared differently in the shader and you use them differently.